# React.Component doesn’t implement shouldComponentUpdate?

Tags: reactjs

According to the docs, React.Component doesn't implement `shouldComponentUpdate` ?

So how about a lifecycle of a component ([the-component-lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle)) ([shouldcomponentupdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate)) ?

> React.PureComponent is similar to React.Component. The difference
>   between them is that React.Component doesn’t implement
>   shouldComponentUpdate(), but React.PureComponent implements it with a
>   shallow prop and state comparison.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: @DanielReina As you can see, in one part of the docs, they say that `React.Component` doesn't implements `shouldComponentUpdate` function, which seem not to be true, accroding to the other part of the docs.

Answer (score 2):

By default, using `Component`, `shouldComponentUpdate` returns true (no diffing of props happens), unless its defined by you (result dependent of what you put in). Using `PureComponent` react does a shallow diff of props by default.

Feel free to take a look at the react source code, roughly, it checks if `shouldComponentUpdate` is defined and is a function. Then checks if it is a pure component, then returns true by default.

https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberClassComponent.js

Comment: So, when we're extending `Component` class, react doesn't perform any checks and always re-renders whole component -_-?

Comment: Correct, if you look at the react source code https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberClassComponent.js line 157 `checkShouldComponentUpdate`

Comment: In every tutorial, first thing to mention is always react shadow DOM and the fact, that react always update only necessary part of the component. So, accoring to everything you wrote above, it's not true? Or maybe i'm missing something?

Comment: I see your point, I might be wrong on this one...but just because it `should` update it doesn't mean it `will` update